# What are the oxidation states of galium and arsenic in GaAs semiconductor?

Tags: oxidation-state, semiconductors

According to the book I'm referring to ("S.M. Sze Semiconductor Devices"), gallium has an oxidation state of +1 and arsenic has that of -1. This should not be possible as each of these elements forms a covalent bond with four atoms of the other element ([structure of GaAs semiconductor](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Gallium-arsenide-unit-cell-3D-balls.png)). For that to be possible, shouldn't both of them have one electron in $\ce{3s}$ subshell and three electrons in $\ce{3p}$ subshell?

Comment: Which book?  And how meaningful are these oxidation states anyway?

Comment: Oxidation states are meaningful because they tell about the electronic configuration that might have existed during bonding

Comment: @OscarLanzi The book I'm referring to is S.M. Sze Semiconductor Devices

Answer (score 2):

In general, gallium can have +1 and +3 oxidation states, though +1 is a very rare condition. In its turn arsenic possible oxidation states are -3, +3 and +5. As it is stated in Wikipedia, gallium oxidation state in gallium arsenide is +3. Once again, arsenic has -3 oxidation state in arsenides or intermetallic compounds. Therefore, gallium arsenide oxidation states are +3 for Ga and -3 for As. This is logical because the electronegativity of As is higher then Ga. As for Simon Sze, he is an electrical engineer and physicist and not a chemist. From the mathematical point of view (-3)(+3) is the same thing as (-1)(+1).